# Pytest different setup teardown with the webdriver initialization

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I need to run Selenium tests with the pytest as a runner.
So, I need to create webdriver as a fixture, but also I need to create some test preconditions (setup and teardown).
Its easy to define webdriver in the setup method.
But I need to have more than 100+ different preconditions (setup) and I think, its a bad practice to copy-paste driver setup in each of them.
And I need to have same `webdriver` accessible from the `setup` and `test_` methods.
What I have now is:

```
#conftest.py

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser")

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def browser(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--browser")


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def driver(browser):
     if browser == 'firefox':
         web_driver = webdriver.Firefox()
     elif browser == 'edge':
        web_driver = webdriver.Edge()  # dk:needs to be added the path
     else:
         options = Options()
         options.add_argument(arguments)
         web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    web_driver = browser
    yield web_driver
    web_driver.quit()
```

```
#test_case.py

@pytest.fixture
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver")
def resource_module_1(driver):
    print('setup')
    driver.get(some_link)
    driver.click(some_button)
    yield 
    print("teardown")


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("resource_module_1")
class TestOne:

    def test_one(self):
        # I need to have driver there for UI tests
        print('test_1')

    def test_two(self):
        print('test_2')
```

But I do not have access to the `driver` in the test methods. Also this code looks bad.

Comment: Why not yield the driver in `resource_module_1` and refer to it in your tests: do `def test_one(self, resource_module_1)` so you can use it? It's pretty standard.

Comment: In this case is it the good practise to use two fixture decorators on the `resource_module_1` function? Or maybe there are some another best practices to use multiple setups/teardowns but without copy-paste driver init to each of them?

Comment: You don't need the `@pytest.mark.usefixtures` decorator if you use the fixture anyway in `resource_module_1`.